# Pulling values with javascript using d3.nest for force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add some summary statistics to my force directed D3 graph. I can see the array with console.log(d), but when I try to use the simplest javascript I can't seem to pull the values from the array. Here is the pertinent code:

```
function fade(opacity) {
return d => {
  node.style('stroke-opacity', function (o) {
    const thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;

    console.log(d)

     var new_data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(j) { return j.group;})
      .rollup(function(j) {
       return d3.sum(j, function(g) {return g.contribution_total; });
      }).map(d); //.entries(d);
      //new_data
      console.log(new_data)

      var expensesByName = d3.nest()
      .key(function(g) { return g.group; })
      .entries(d);
      //.forEach(node);
        console.log(expensesByName )

    var contributionsByName = d3.nest()
      .key(function(g) { return g.contribution_total; })
      .entries(d);
      //.forEach(node);
    //console.log(contributionsByName)
```

Here is where the live attempt lives: http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~jennifer.p/capstone/slider/add_winner_try1.html

All of my console.log() attempts (besides console.log(d)) return an empty array. See picture: [image]

Ultimately I am trying to show a total contribution amount by group (democrat/republican) and then I want to calculate a 'winner' percentage (# nodes with 'W' vs # with null), but right now I just really need help accessing the data period. I've been at this a few hours and it seems so simple, any thoughts are appreciated. TIA!

Comment: I added a baby file to make this easier to test: http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~jennifer.p/capstone/slider/add_summary_stat_toy_v1.html

Comment: why should this grouping (nest) depend on the selected node?

Comment: I'm interested in highlighting characteristics of a subset of the visual. When you double click on a node it creates a new population to comment on (which is the difference between the entire json file and just the d elements). I'm not sure how to aggregate the elements that are flagged when clicked. It seems like each d element is isolated and maybe that's why I am having trouble summing them, and maybe they need to be added to an array, but I can't get at the value within a single d. Did I answer your question?

Comment: why do you work with `fill-opacity` and `stroke-opacity` when they are always the same, just use `opacity`. Has this dbl-click meaning if you dbl-click a non orange node? I get `new_data` total-by-group. What do you want with `expensesByName` and `contributionsByName`?

Comment: I'm pretty new to D3 and didn't realize I could combine them like that. How are you getting new_data to come back??? I don't strictly speaking need the other 2, I was just trying to get anything to come back instead of the empty arrays

Comment: yes, the analysis is more applicable to the industry (orange nodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to collect the nodes connected inside the opacity callback and after setting use the list to calculate the `d3.next`

```
  function fade(opacity) {
    return d => {
      var connectedNodes = [];
      node.style('opacity', function (o) {
        var connected = isConnected(d, o);
        if (connected) { connectedNodes.push(d); }
        return connected ? 1 : opacity;
      });
      var new_data = d3.nest()
          .key(function(j) { return j.group;})
          .rollup(function(j) {
            return d3.sum(j, function(g) {return g.contribution_total; });
          }).entries(connectedNodes);
      console.log('new_data', new_data);
      link.style('opacity', o => (o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity));
    };
  }
```

Why do you have a `click`-handler with `fade(1)` when you also have the `releasenode` handler?

```
.on('click.fade', fade(1))
.on('click',releasenode)
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about push! Its amazing and a huge help :)